# Home Button doesn't terminate multiplayer match on Game Center / Gamekit

Tags: notifications, push-notification, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

First of all I have to say I am new to iOS development.

My problem is during a multiplayer game using Game Center. I don't now how to get a notification from Game Center if the other player (my game is a 2 player game) leaves the game with the home button of the device.

I need to know when one player closes the game since the game always starts from scratch when re-opened, this means, it will show the splash screen and go directly to the main menu. I've tried re-matching but Game Center seems to be creating a new connection and looking for new players, meanwhile player 2 keeps 'playing' with player 1 without any response happening, so his match will never end.

Any method, didChangeState, matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled nor authenticationChanged, the latter being under a notification, seem to do anything when the home button is pressed.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subscribing to `NSNoficationCenter` to find out when your app goes to the background:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(userPressedHomeButton:) 
    name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

In your `userPressedHomeButton:` function you can decide how to notify the other player or suspend the game.  BUT, you must take action quickly, because iOS will not allow your app to run more than a few seconds after it has been suspended.

As an alternate to subscribing to `NSNotificationCenter`, you can do your implementation in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification { }
```